# How to get Eclipse style code completion in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I´m just moving from `Eclipse` to `Android Studio` and I noticed a small difference.
In Eclipse when I use code completion for example like this [image: eclipse code help]

`Eclipse` would complete the code like this and allow me just use tab to jump to next parameter.

```
Log.d(tag, msg)
```

But `Android Studio` does this:

```
Log.d()
```

So is there any setting that would achieve the same result in Android Studio or is this available only in Eclipse

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93591/how-do-i-use-idea-intellij-to-auto-complete-method-parameters maybe? "super completion" looks like it's something similar

Comment: Thanks. "Super completion" does't look that super based on that question and seems there's no parameter completion.

Comment: "use tab to jump to next parameter" is the best !!

Comment: same question posted on Android Developer Tools Community https://plus.google.com/117534008140170831687/posts/Sn1djhcJCxs

Answer (score 0):

In your IDE go to Editor -> Code Completion and make sure that the Autopopup code completion is checked

Comment: Not what I´m asking. The question is about the behavior that happens after you select something that pop ups for completion.