# IntelliJ Super Completion not working

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA for Java and I cannot find a way to have IntelliJ auto-fill a method invocation complete with all arguments.

For example, if I have the following method signature:

fooBar(String A, int b, boolean c) {}

When I invoke it later, I would like IntelliJ IDEA to auto-complete with all the arguments.

Eclipse is able to auto-fill placeholders for your method invocations, just wondering if IntelliJ is able to do this as well.

The `Ctrl + Shift + Space` key combination does not auto-complete the method invocation, it only brings up a list of parameters and I am forced to add one by one.

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93591/how-do-i-use-idea-intellij-to-auto-complete-method-parameters), they say starting from IntelliJ 9 Super Completion will allow the completion of all arguments which IntelliJ 8 will only allow the completion of one parameter at a time.

In my situation, my `Ctrl+Shift+Space` behavior is the same as IntelliJ 8, which only allows me to complete one argument at a time.

Comment: Try Ctrl+Space. And - What system are you running? My friends who work on linux have many issues with shortcuts being caught by gnome. You may try to change Keymap in settings. Search for "Completion".

Answer (score 0):

"Super completion" in IntelliJ IDEA works only when it's possible to substitute all arguments automatically without putting in placeholders (for example, when you're calling a super method, or when you otherwise have variables in scope with names and types that match the parameters of the methods you're calling).

There is no feature in IntelliJ that works exactly like Eclipse and substitutes placeholders for all arguments of any call that you then need to fill.