# Intellij call method: how to auto complete with all arguments

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij call method: how to auto complete with all arguments?

For example: method foo

```
public class Foo {
    public void doSomething(int name, int value, int somethingElse) {
        ...

    }
}
```

In subclass Bar

```
public class Bar extends Foo {
    @Override
    public void doSomething(int name, int value, int somethingElse) {
       super.doSomething(_);

     }

}
```

calling superclass doSomething(..) method, its arguments are not auto completed, and i have to type in all arguments with the same names.

Same issue as calling methods of other classes. In eclipse, they will
be auto completed by best guess. How to achieve this in Intellij?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use IntelliJ to auto-complete method parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93591/how-do-i-use-intellij-to-auto-complete-method-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Code | Completion | SmartType` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>:

[image]